# Initialize Page variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to initialize the `Page`?

`Page<SomeKindOfList> lists = null`

or is there a better way like for List

`List<SomeKindOfList> thisIsAList = new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [PageImpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html#PageImpl-java.util.List-) constructor

> Creates a new PageImpl with the given content. This will result in the created Page being identical to the entire List.

For [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImplUnitTests.java):

> ```
> List<String> list = Collections.emptyList();
> Page<String> page = new PageImpl<>(list);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PageImpl implementation of Page interface below code to initialize Page

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5);
        List<SomeKindOfList> list= new ArrayList<>();
        Page<SomeKindOfList> page = 
            new PageImpl<>(list, pageable, list.size());
```